# Force Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I just got burned because I used `find_index` on an array on my dev box (OSX with Ruby 1.8.7) and the deployment machine runs Ruby 1.8.6. (What's the difference between `find_index` and `index`? The latter works on 1.8.7 and 1.8.6)

So that got me thinking: **what's the best way to force Rails to run with a specific Ruby version?**

Since it's probably relevant (install multiple rubys!), I need to know this for OSX, but it would be useful to know for Linux, Windows, and Commodore 64 as well.

**Later:** Of course I'm working in a virtual appliance now, but I'd like to be able to control my Ruby versions if possible on my computer.

**Note:** I don't care too much disallowing Rails running with the wrong Ruby version. I'm more interested in getting the RIGHT ruby version to run. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately, the highest version of Ruby that runs on the C64 is Ruby 0.7.  Probably not worth it to support it.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but if you want to care less about differences in the version of Ruby you're running, you can 'require "backports"'.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune everything is an answer that helps with the problem in general. What's the link for that? I see the project on github...

Comment: I posted that as an answer then (with link to github)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't force the version of ruby required but you may want to utilize something like RVM to easily manage your ruby environment on your dev and production boxes.

http://rvm.io/

This allows you to easily switch and maintain multiple versions of ruby on your system.

Comment: Nice, I'll check it out. I don't manage the production boxes, but I'd like to know what's possible.

Comment: Yes at the very least you can easily adjust your local machine to match your production server. Also - you should look into having your sysadmin upgrade to 1.8.7 as there are a lot of security / performance issues with with 1.8.6

Answer (score 4):

This is brute force and ignorance, but one approach would be

```
raise "Wrong ruby version, please use ruby 1.8.7" unless RUBY_VERSION == "1.8.7"
```

Comment: Well, that's definitely part of the question, thanks for that. I'm kind of asking about the other side, how to get the right ruby to run.

Answer (score 1):

Use the RUBY_VERSION constant in your Application controller.
This shows rendering the 500 error page. You would want to setup a new page in your public dir with an appropriate message.

before_filter :check_ruby_version

def check_ruby_version
  unless RUBY_VERSION == "1.8.7"
    render :file => File.join(Rails.public_path, '500.html'), :status => 500
  end
end

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to put that in the environment.rb so the app doesn't start in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at the problem would be to be able to disregard differences in the version of Ruby you're running. My [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem brings Ruby 1.8.6 up to date in the 1.8.x line (including the upcoming 1.8.8) and much of 1.9:

```
require "backports"
```

Or instead, for the less courageous among us, you can require only 1.8.7's features:

```
require "backports/1.8.7"
```